# Game crashes upon logging into Google Play Games services

Tags: android, sdk, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I am creating a 2d game in unity and I have ran into a problem. I have created a developer account for google play and published my game to google play as closed alpha. I am now adding google play games services to the game and I downloaded the latest library from:(https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) and imported it into Unity. I have set everything up but the Game crashes upon attempting to login.

```
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
using System.Collections;

public class gpgTest : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () {
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
        // enables saving game progress.
        .EnableSavedGames()
        // require access to a player's Google+ social graph (usually not needed)
        .RequireGooglePlus()
        .Build();
    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
    // recommended for debugging:
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    // Activate the Google Play Games platform
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
}

void Update () {
}

public void LogIn()
{
    Debug.Log("button");
    // authenticate user:
    Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
        // handle success or failure
    });
}
}
```

note: I have tried almost all versions of the library and different versions of Unity 5.0 and up.

I also get these messages:
[image: Unity console]

And I did install all the necesary packages in the sdk manager.

Answer (score 0):

OK so for all of those struggling like me the answer is in removing all files with version 10.2.1 in \Assets\Plugins\Android\ and replacing them with ones of version 10.0.1.

Source: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1604

In short: the play games plugin is not compatible with newer libraries.

Another related thread:http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1324988/android-game-crashes-on-startup-becaus-of-google-p.html

Edit: only Unity version 5.0 - 5.5 is supported (for now)